# Unable to save response data to instance's fields; other data in same block is saved correctly (Django/Celery)

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I'm running a task to create an account on a third-party service and save relevant data from that service's response to my `profile` object. The task is running and the data is getting returned correctly but not being properly saved on the object.

Relevant code:

```
    # payload is generated in helper method. if that was the point of
    # failure, i'd see an error
    result = self.third_party_client.post(self.creation_endpoint, payload)

    json_result = result.json()

    if json_result.get('Error') != 'SUCCESS':
        # Account Creation Failed. error is handled.
    else:
        # Currently I log this on our staging server to make sure
        # the data's coming back properly; it is returned as expected
        self.logger.error('CoreCard Account Created. Data: {}'.format(json_result))
        profile = user.profile
        profile.account_number = json_result.get('AccountNumber')
        profile.card_number_last_four = int(json_result.get('CardNumber')[12:])
        profile.customer_id = json_result.get('CustomerID')
        profile.account_creation_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        profile.save()
```

So if I then query this `profile` instance, it has the `account_creation_datetime` value as expected, but the other fields are blank. I've checked the logs and the `json_result` values are all correct.

Now here's where it's a bit weird. Where I think it's actually failing is the celery task that calls the utility that runs this bit of code. If I run this utility manually, the fields are saved properly. If I run it as part of our normal workflow (called within an async task), the account is created on the third-party service so I know this code is executing, but the `profile` fields (except for `account_creation_datetime`) are blank. The task looks like this:

```
@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=3)
def create_account_task(self, guid):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(historical_id=guid)
    profile.account_creation_worker_id = current_task.request.id # Per http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.current_task
    profile.save()

    # Sanity Check
    if profile.approval_date is not None:
        util = CoreCardUtility()
        util.create_corecard_account(profile.user)
        return True
    return False
```

In this workflow, `profile.account_creation_worker_id` is *also* not saved correctly, even if I know the task ran because the account is created on the third-party service.

I'm at a bit of a loss — is there an issue with Celery workers or threading that I'm missing here?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To get the task ID (for celery version above 2.2.0),

```
profile.account_creation_worker_id = create_account_task.request.id
```

instead of

```
profile.account_creation_worker_id = current_task.request.id
```

Probably, your task is not running and must be throwing error. Have you checked celery log?

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks for your comment! I don't believe this is the error; the account would not be created on the third-party service if the task was not running. We use the `current_task` pattern per the celery docs; it has worked successfully everywhere else. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.current_task